# how to delete files from both db and folder

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

hi I wants to delete a file from both db and its folder `public/files` I have written some code but that's only delete from db not from folder

code:

```php
        public function destroy($id)
        {
            $file = File::find($id);
            $file->delete(public_path('files'));

            $file->delete();

            return redirect('file')->with('success', 'Data is successfully deleted');
        }

my db table:

        Schema::create('files', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('filename');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

how to do this

Answer (score 0):

```php
    public function destroy($id)
    {
            $file = File::find($id);
            unlink(public_path('file'));

            $file->delete();

            return redirect('file')->with('success', 'Data is successfully deleted');
    }
```

Comment: unlink(D:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\webpro7\public\file path): No such file or directory

Comment: `public_path('file')` where `file` is your path for example i have `public/uploads/file1.jpg` then it should be `unlink(public_path('uploads/file1.jpg'));`

Comment: unlink(D:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\webpro7\public\files): Permission denied

Comment: you have to change permission of `files` folder

Comment: how can I do that

Answer (score 0):

Use `Unlink()` function for delete from directory and DB query for delete from DB.

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
        $file = File::find($id);
        $file_path = $file->path; //Please use that variable ehich you are using to save file path.
        unlink($file_path); //it will looks like file/path/image.png

        $file->delete();

        return redirect('file')->with('success', 'Data is successfully deleted');
    }
```

Hope it will work. Thanks!

Comment: unlink(): Invalid argument

Comment: Pass file path in `unlike()` eg: `unlink('public/folder/image.png')`. For more information read this:- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php

Answer (score 0):

PHP `unlink` function is used to delete a file from directory

> Step 1 : First you need to fetch the file path from the DB.
>
> Step 2 : use unlink('path_name') to delete the file from directory
>
> Step 3 : Delete the row from the DB

```
 public function destroy($id){
   
    $FilePath=DB::table('files')->select('filename')->where('id',$id)->first();
    
    $path = public_path()."/uploads/".$FilePath->filename;
    unlink($path); // Delete From Folder
    
    $result=DB::table('files')->where('id',$id)->delete();  // Delete From DB
   
    return redirect('file')->with('success', 'Data is successfully deleted');
}
```

**Update**

`unlink` is an PHP function, In Laravel way, use the `File::delete() .`

Example : `File::delete($filename);`

must include `use File;` in your file

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'file_path' in 'field list' (SQL: select `file_path` from `files` where `column_name` = 6 limit 1)

Comment: @programmer0001 `file_path` is sample name, please use your own table name and column name

Comment: I hv changed the table_name and column_name  but now it says:   SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'file_path' in 'field list' (SQL: select `file_path` from `files` where `filename` = 6 limit 1)  ,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,I update question and shown my db table in question

Comment: Undefined variable: Id   at this line:   $FilePath=DB::table('files')->select('filename')->where('id',$Id)->first();